# What is WebGL2RenderingContext.attachShader?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm currently going through [this WebGL tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context) and the section that I'm on is supposed to teach you to draw a white square on a black canvas. Not very exciting, and especially unexciting since all I'm getting is a black canvas.

The firefox console says "Argument 2 of WebGL2RenderingContext.attachShader is not an object." [This doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL2RenderingContext) for `WebGL2RenderingContext` doesn't saying anything about `attachShader` (which is called on lines 4 and 5 of `initShaders`). I also find it strange that the function `getShader` isn't passed a 3rd argument even though it's defined with 3.

Another possible issue, unrelated to what firefox says, might have to do with the fact that when I tried to keep the shader scripts and main script in separate files nothing was displayed on the page when I opened it. This could be a problem because the tutorial uses 2 scripts that I had to download from github [here](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/tree/gh-pages/tutorial).

Here is index.html, all my code is almost exactly the same as the tutorial, but I made it slightly more concise because they were essentially redefining functions that are already a part of the API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    //the two scripts from github
    <script src="sylvester.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="glUtils.js" type="text/javascript"/>

    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="shader-vs">
    //vertex shader goes here   
    </script>
    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="shader-fs">
    //frag shader goes here
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //main javascript goes here
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
  <canvas id="glCanvas" width="640" height="480">
    Your browser doesn't appear to support the
    <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code> element.
  </canvas>
</body>
```

the main javascript:

```
var canvas;
var gl;
var squareVerticesBuffer;
var mvMatrix;
var shaderProgram;
var vertexPositionAttribute;
var perspectiveMatrix;
var horizAspect = 480.0/640.0;
function setMatrixUniforms(){
    var pUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pUniform, false, new Float32Array(perspectiveMatrix.flatten()));
    var mvUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mvUniform, false, new Float32Array(mvMatrix.flatten()));
}

function getShader(gl, id, type){
    var shaderScript , theSource, currentChild, shader;
    shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!shaderScript){
        console.log("Couldn't find shader script");
        return null;
    }
    theSource = shaderScript.text;
    if(!type){
        if(shaderScript.type == 'x-shader/x-fragment'){
            type = gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER;
        }
        else if (shaderScript.type == 'x-shader/x-vertex'){
            type = gl.VERTEX_SHADER;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Shader is not of a valid type");
            return null;
        }
    }
    shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    if(!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
        console.log("An error occured compiling the shaders:"
            + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        gl.deleteShader(shader);
        return null;
    }
    return shader;
}

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, 'shader-fs');
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, 'shader-vs');

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
    if(!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        console.log('Unable to initialize the shader program: '
            + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    }
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
    vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);
}

function initBuffers(){
    squareVerticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVerticesBuffer);
    var vertices = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

function drawScene(){
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    perspectiveMatrix = makePerspective(45, 4.0/3.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    //perspectiveMatrix = makePerspective(45, 640.0/480.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    mvMatrix = Matrix.I(4);
    mvMatrix.x(Matrix.Translation($V([-0.0, 0.0, -6.0])).ensure4x4())
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVerticesBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

function start() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('glCanvas');
    // Initialize the GL context
    var opts = { };
    gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl2", opts );
    if(!gl) gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl2", opts);
    if(!gl) gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", opts);
    if(!gl) gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", opts);

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    setInterval(drawScene, 15);
}
```

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

frag shader:

```
void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggested [these tutorials](https://webgl2fundamentals.org).

Comment: Hey, the doc you are follow is based on `webgl`, but in your code, the context your get is for `webgl2` :)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

gl.attachShader isn't exclusive to WebGL 2. Its a function that is available from any WebGL context. It's used to tie vertex\fragment shaders together to a program to setup a rendering state [[Link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/attachShader).

To go more in depth into what this tutorial is attempting to convey, I've provided a sample below. Hopefully you find it useful.

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- lets the browser know that this is a HTML page -->

<html>
 <head>
  <!-- UTF-8 Encoding, it'll complain if you don't use this -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Just some inlined CSS to style and center the canvas -->
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 3px white;
    border-radius: 20px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 
  <!-- 
   The script "type" doesn't matter, we just want to use it to load shader source code
   If it isn't labled as a valid JS type the browser won't try to execute it
  -->
  <script id="vertexShader" type="glShader">
   precision lowp float;
   
   attribute vec2 aPos;
   
   void main() {
    // If you are just making a square you don't need a projection matrix
    // The 2D coordinates are in the range of X: -1 -> +1 Y: -1 -> + 1
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos,0.0,1.0);
   }
   
  </script>
  <script id="fragmentShader" type="glShader">
   precision lowp float;
   
   void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
   }
  </script>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   
   // If you only want to draw a simple 2D shape, you don't really need to use any matricies
   
   // -- WebGL Variables --
   var canvas = null; // A reference to the canvas (It doesn't contain the canvas it just has it's address)
   var gl = null; // A reference for the webGL context (You don't need to use WebGL 2)
   var VBO = null; // A reference for an OpenGL buffer that I'll use to store "Vertex Data"
   var program = null; // A reference to an OpenGL program, you can think of it as something similar to 
        // a .exe in GPU memory that contains the code from your shaders
   
   // ---------------------
   
   // -- Normal Variables --
   var width = 320; // Size of the canvas to set (in pixels)
   var height = 240;
   
   // A "Typed" array of 32 bit floats that will contain the vertex data that'll be uploaded to the gpu in the VBO buffer 
   // (VBO means vertex buffer object, I.E. a buffer used to contain vertex data)
   // A full vertex (all the data for one corner of a mesh) would be a complete list of attributes for the vertex shader.
   // e.g.
   //
   // if in the vertex shader you had
   // attribute vec2 pos;
   // attribute vec3 colour;
   //
   // Then a single vertex would be a sequence of five floats that are split into these attribute values
   // e.g. 50.0, 50.0, 1.0,1.0,1.0,
   // would become
   // pos = vec2(50.0,50.0);
   // colour = vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0);
   //
   // The reason it's put into a "Float32Array" is so WebGL knows without having to do any checks that the
   // array you just gave it is exactly a list of 32 floats
   // You don't strictly need to do that as WebGL can figure out the type, its just not encouraged as it has quite the performance impact
   
   // Only has 1 attribute -> Pos 2D Vector
   // Triangles are drawn in groups of three verticies
   var squareVerticies = Float32Array.from([
    // Top right -> top left -> bottom right (Its best to do triangles counter clockwise, look up gl.CULL_FACE for why is this the case)
     0.5, 0.5,
    -0.5, 0.5,
     0.5,-0.5,
     
     // Bottom Right -> top left -> bottom left
     0.5,-0.5,
    -0.5, 0.5,
    -0.5,-0.5
   ]);
   // ----------------------
   
   // Called after the page has loaded
   window.onload = function() {
    // Get canvas reference and set size
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    
    // get WebGL context reference
    // No need to do checking, as 99% of modern browsers support WebGL
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    
    // In essence to draw your square you need to seperate things
    // A program (made of a vertex and fragment shader) that will say how to render the square
    // And some input data (In this case the VBO) that will be what you want to render (The coordinates of the square)
    // So each one should be considered seperately and can be setup in either order
    
    // -- Program Setup --
    
    // Extract shader code from script tags
    var vertexShaderCode = document.getElementById("vertexShader").innerHTML;
    var fragmentShaderCode = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").innerHTML;
    
    // Create references to brand new shaders in GPU memory
    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    // Upload shader source code
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexShaderCode);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderCode);
    
    // Compile Shaders
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    
    // This function returns true/false depending on if the shaders compiled correctly
    // In this case I'm checking if either one is false, I.e. if either failed to compile
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ||
     !gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
     
     // This runs if either shader had an error
     console.error(
      "Vertex Shader: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader) + "\n" +
      "Fragment Shader: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)
     );
     
     // Release shader references since we don't need them if they don't work
     gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
     gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
     
     // End the function early since no rendering will work with broken shaders
     return;
    }
    
    // At this point if there is no error, you have a valid vertex & fragment shader in GPU memory
    // But to be able to use them the two shaders need to be linked to gether
    // The "Thing" that will hold them together is called a program
    
    // Create reference to a new program in GPU memory (GPU memory is just RAM thats physically part of the GPU, often called VRAM)
    program = gl.createProgram();
    
    // attachShader is used to link a vertex shader then a fragment shader with a new program
    gl.attachShader(program,vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
    
    // Once you have two shaders attached linkProgram glues everything together and makes it ready for rendering
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    
    // You can now delete the shader references since the program now contains them
    gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
    gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
     
    // And if you want to use different shaders, all you have to do is switch the current program
    gl.useProgram(program);
     
    // -------------------
    
    // -- Vertex Buffer (VBO) Setup --
    
    // this just creates a generic empty block of memory on the GPU you can use for anything!
    // (These blocks are called buffers)
    VBO = gl.createBuffer();
    
    // In WebGL and OpenGL if you want to operate on peices of data in GPU memory (buffers & textures mostly)
    // They aren't directly access with a variable name but you need to "bind" them to the gl context
    // Think of it as having this kind of effect
    //   currentBuffer = VBO;
    //  currentBuffer.doThing()
    
    // This looks confusing but ARRAY_BUFFER is just the name of a varialbe in WebGL
    // Its a reference that is being set to the new buffer (literally just ARRAY_BUFFER = VBO)
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
    
    // This uploads the vertex data explained earlier to the GPU
    //  Here ARRAY_BUFFER = VBO
    //  squareVerticies is the data being uploaded
    //  and STATIC_DRAW is a hint to WebGL, its just giving it a hint what we intend to do with the data
    //  all STATIC_DRAW means is that we're uploading some data we're going to use to render but we aren't going to be changing it
    //  WebGL uses these hints to optimize the memory layout on the GPU, it does all this for you
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,squareVerticies,gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    // -------------------------
    
    // and that is generally all you need to do to setup for rendering
    // All thats left is to make sure that the program you want to use is set and you tell 
    // WebGL how to feed data from the VBO (squareVerticies on the GPU)
    // Into the vertex shader
    
    // The vertex shader operates on a single vertex at a time, and a vertex in terms of data is each collection of the attributes you made in the vertex shader
    // that can be taken from your VBO.
    //
    // E.G.
    // for this setup I'm using one attribute, "attribute vec2 aPos;"
    //  that would mean every two floats in the array form one complete vertex
    //  So what I need to do is tell WebGL that data format
    
    var posAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"aPos");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
     posAttributeLocation, // The index of the attribute I'm telling you about
     2, // The number of floats in that attribute (2D vector => 2 floats)
     gl.FLOAT, // The type of data I'm using,
     gl.FALSE, // If to normalize (You can ignore this, just keep it as false or gl.FALSE)
     2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, // The total size of a complete vertex in bytes (it's the number of floats of all the attributes combined * The size of a float in bytes (4 bytes) )
     0 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT // The offset in bytes that this attribute is at from the beginning of a vertex 
    );          // E.G. a float attribute thats after a 2D vector attribute would have an offset of 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = 8 bytes
    
    // The last step per attribute is to tell WebGL to "turn on" use of this attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(posAttributeLocation);
    
    // Repeating that process for each attribute will tell WebGL how to send the data to your vertex shader
    // This is also called setting up the buffers state
    // It's also worthy to keep in mind that when you bind a different buffer you will need to repeat this step, because until you repeat your calls to vertexAttribPointer.
    // Your vertex shader will still receive data from the previous buffer
    
    // Set RGBA value for the background color
    gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);
    
    // Clears the canvas with the colour you gave
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    // Draw using triangles from index 0 in the buffer to index 6 (With triangles it must be a factor of 3)
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0,6);
   }
   
   // Called when the page is about to close
   // Here I'll let go off the resources I asked WebGL to get on the GPU
   window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
    gl.deleteBuffer(VBO);
    gl = null;
   }
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```